# Arraylist in arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

User input in console:  `jack look`

What I want to do is to create two arraylists with `jack` and `look`. To achieve this I first analyzed jack and look separately and send them to arraylist name words(); The  hard part of this is input can contain 3 or 100 words.

I need to define arraylist size of words.count. It is like arraylist in arraylist...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            int ü = 0;
            while (ü == 0)
            {
                ArrayList words = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList merdum = new ArrayList();

                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] kelimeler = s.Split(' ');

                for (int i = 0; i < kelimeler.Length; i++)
                {
                    string a = kelimeler[i];
                    string[] kökler = Regex.Split(a, @"\W+");

                    words.Add(kökler);

                    foreach (string kelime in kökler)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(kelime);
                    }
                }

                words.Sort();
                int count = words.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    ArrayList words(i) =new ArrayList();
                    // this is where i need help                     
                }

                words.Add(kelimeler);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        // @      special verbatim string synta
        // \W+    one or more non-word characters together
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag c# as your programming language.

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`, it is pretty much depracated. Use `List<T>` instead, here `List<string>`. It is dynamic and will grow as needed..

Comment: What is your question? What is it that you want the code to actually do? Most of this code doesn't make sense: you are sorting a list of arrays (arrays aren't comparable), and you add an array to the `words` list just before you loop back and throw the list away when you re-initialize the `words` variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Probably, you should just go talk to your teacher for this assignment...they will know what the actual result should be, and can also do their job and help teach you what you're supposed to learn here.

Comment: its just that :  i wanna create an arraylist for each word submitted by user. and lists must have same name with submited word. ( when user input is a sentence , i sent  all words to arraylist to seperate them .)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using multi-dimensional arrays instead if you are using a for loop inside a foor loop. If that´s something you didn´t already think about of course.